# How to bulk deselect "stop time" for songs and movies in iTunes

Tags: windows, itunes

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

For some reason, the majority of my songs and movies (80%, nearing 5000) have a "stop time" checked – which I did not put on (under *Get Info » Options*). This is extremly annoying as some movies will only play for 10 seconds and some for 2 hours.

I don't want to go through every file individually as this would take days. How is it possible to mass-unselect the stop time and/or start time?

Note that it's not a issue of corrupted files since when I deselect the stop time, the song or video fully plays to the proper ending.

Answer (score 1):

For other fields, when you select multiple items then view their properties, you are then able to edit all of them at once.  Fields are usually blank if they differ, but if you touch them they should force updates on all of them.